# How do I track plays when using Facebook's News Feed player?

Tags: facebook, jwplayer, facebook-opengraph

Facebook allows you to embed videos in the News Feed through the use of OpenGraph. I am using JWPlayer to play the videos and I used Longtail's [tutorial](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player) to setup the meta data. The issue I am having is how to track when a user plays the video in the News Feed.

I have figured out that Facebook uses the meta tag "og:video" to play the video but I am having trouble crafting the URL to include a callback URL for tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a server side handler to serve up videos and just track the video from the handler.

Essentially the URL of your video could be `http://example.com/video-handler.php`
Have the content type of the response be set to something like video/mp4.
When the page is requested, record the event with however you are tracking you videos.
Then serve up the content of the actual video being requested.